# What's the difference between these 2 ifs?

Tags: java

```
if(loadFactor != null && !(trialExists(loadFactor))
```

and

```
if(!(loadFactor == null || trialExists(loadFactor))
```

I was asked in a review to make 1st if changed to 2nd. How does it make any difference.

Comment: If you show this to a mathematician who knows the meanings of `!`, `&&` and `||`, he/she will be confused when you suggest there is a difference. However, there is a subtle difference, namely that of [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: Wait, there is no difference! They probably ask you to do the first, because some people find [DeMorgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeMorgan%27s_Law) confusing and harder to read.

Comment: `!a && !b` == `!(a || b)` and `!a || !b` == `!(a && b)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no difference.

In both cases:

- If `loadFactor` is null, `trialExists(loadFactor)` won't be evaluated, and the condition will be false, so it won't enter into the `if` body
- Otherwise, `trialExists(loadFactor)` will be evaluated, and the condition will be the opposite of the result - so it will only enter the body of the `if` statement if `trialExists(loadFactor)` returns false

This is because both `&&` and `||` are *short-circuiting*:

- If the first operand of `&&` is `false`, the second operand isn't evaluated and the result is just `false`
- If the first operand of `||` is `true`, the second operand isn't evaluated and the result is just `true`

Personally I prefer the first piece of code to the second. It reads to me as "If we've got a load factor, and there's no trial for it." The second piece of code is more obscure, because the inner condition is "if we don't have a load factor or it's an existing trial" - which isn't a particularly natural condition to express, in my view.

Answer (score 6):

They were asking you to show how [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) work, using an example in Java.

> "not (A and B)" is the same as "(not A) or (not B)"
>
> and also,
>
> "not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)"

(from *Wikipedia*)

1. So starting with:

   ```
   loadFactor != null && !(trialExists(loadFactor)
   ```
2. We add double negation:

   ```
   !!(loadFactor != null && !(tiralExists(loadFactor))
   ```
3. Then we can transform according to first law (not (A and B) is the same as (not A) or (not B))

   ```
   !(!(loadFactor != null) || !!(trialExists(loadFactor)))
   ```
4. Now we can remove double negations:

   ```
   !(loadFactor == null || trialExists(loadFactor))
   ```

And we get 2nd if statement from your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. Both will not evaluate the second condition if loadFactor is Null and hence are good.

The reviewer might have thought that first is not the case of Short circuit and will evaluate second condition if loadFactor is Null.

Comment: How can the first possibly throw an NPE? The second operand of the `&&` won't be evaluated, due to short-circuiting. You appear to believe that only `||` performs short-circuiting - `&&` does as well.

Comment: `if (X && Y)` means if X is false it will return false without evaluating Y, too.

Answer (score 1):

Both cases rely on short-circuit evaluation to avoid calling the function with a null argument.  && doesn't evaluate secnnd arg if first is true, while || doesn't evaluate second- arg is first arg is false.

So the answer is that it makes no difference, except in style.

The first form is clearer, because it is only coincidental that you want the negation of trialExists() in this particular case.